# make impossible to insert data into database if it conflicts with existing data

Tags: django

I would like to make impossible to insert data to my database if that data conflicts with some another data that already exists in my base. What I mean:

Let's say that I would like to insert into database fields `start_date` and `end_date` with the following condition:

-period `(start_date; end_date)` cannot intersect with any other periods in my base

Is any nice and fast way to check it in django?

Possible I can iterate over whole database manually, but maybe is there any nice wrapper?

Comment: Do you want uniqueness on a single field, eg: if a `Company` already exists with a praticular name, then do not allow to insert another `Company` with the same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest doing something like the following:

```
lower = Entry.objects.filter(start_date__lte=new_start)
lower = lower.filter(end_date_gte=new_start)

upper = Entry.objects.filter(start_date__lte=new_end)
upper = upper.filter(end_date_gte=new_end)

valid = len(lower) == 0 and len(upper) == 0

if valid:
    # Do the insert
    pass
```